# c++ how differentiate between base classes in a derived class?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I understand this isn't the best title but I'm not sure how to explain this problem that I'm having without examples.

I have a base class (called vector3)

```
class vector3 {

    protected:
        double x,y,z;
public:
    vector3(): x(0),y(0),z(0) {}
    vector3(double xin, double yin, double zin): x(xin),y(yin),z(zin) {}
    ~vector3() {}

 //...other stuff

};
```

Then I have another class, derived from vector3, called vector4:

```
class vector4 : public vector3 {

protected:
    double ct;
public:

    vector4(): vector3(0,0,0), ct=0 {}

    vector4(double ctin): ct(ctin) {}

    vector4(double ctin, double xin, double yin, double zin):
        vector3(xin, yin, zin), ct(ctin) {}

    vector4(double ctin, vector3 v):
        vector3(v.getx(), v.gety(), v.getz()), ct(ctin) {}

    ~vector4() {}

//...more other stuff

};
```

And that's all fine, but now I've got a class called `particle` defined like this:

```
class particle : public vector4 {
    protected:
        //vector4 r;
        double mass;
        //vector3 beta;
    public:
        particle(): vector4(0,0,0,0), mass=0, vector3(0,0,0) {}

        particle(vector4 rin, double massin, vector3 betain):
            vector4(rin.getx(),rin.gety(),rin.getz(),rin.getct()),
            mass=0,
            vector3(betain.getx(),betain.gety(),betain.getz()) {}

        ~particle() {}
        //...Further stuff
    };
```

So now the question is:
How do I return the x value, y value and z value of the particle's position, and the x value, y value and z value of the particle's beta vector inside a function in the particle class?

With vector 4 I'd just do:

```
double getx() const {
    return x;
}
double gety() const {
    return y;
}
```

etc, but what would I use in the particle's class?

Comment: I believe it's a bad idea to use inheritance in this case. Is a *particle* really a vector? Or does it have *a* position?

Comment: Well exactly. A vector4 is not a vector3, and a particle is not a vector. Inheritance models "is-a" relationships, and that's clearly not what you have here, so you're using the wrong language feature for what you want to do. Favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: Usually you have a component vector position and another vector speed for each particle, or something along those lines.

Comment: Protip: the compiler automatically generates empty destructors for you without you needing to do anything. Don't bother with things like `~vector3() {}`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes But I lose marks if I don't... :)

Comment: @captainjamie you might add a comment telling the teacher that the compiler generated destructor does exactly what it needs to do. He (hopefully) just wants to know that you dont forget destructors when writing a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Position and beta vector are attributes of a particle, so you should be using aggregation instead of inheritance:

```
class particle {
    protected:
        vector4 r;
        double mass;
        vector3 beta;
    // ...
```

You should only use inheritance where there is an *is-a* relationship between the subclass and superclass.

Comment: Right, ok, that seems like a more sensible way to go about it, yes. I'll give people a few more minutes for suggestions before marking an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, particle is a vector4, so you can define your getters public in vector4, and directly call `particle.getX()`

However, this does not seem to be a good idea, in my opinion, particle should contain a vector since it is not a specialisation of the vector4 class.

so let's say particle has a vector called `_vector`

you can define a method like this :

```
double getX(void) const
{
  return (_vector.getX());
}
```

Same goes for `getY`

Comment: Ok, suppose beta was a vector4 also though, how would I return it then?